# QTableView "ResizeToContents" columns are too wide with sorting enabled

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have two identical QTableViews, one of which is sortable.  Both of these tables have the last four columns with their resize mode set to QHeaderView::ResizeToContents.

The non-sortable table column widths seem correct, with just a few pixels of padding on the left and right edges of the column headers.  But the sortable table column widths are adding about 30 pixels to the left and right edges of the column headers, making them much wider than they need to be.

The construction of these tables and their models is identical, except for the single line setSortingEnabled(bool).

Is this by design, or is there a way I can remove all this extra padding from the sortable table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the extra padding is due to the need for the `QHeaderView` to draw the sort indicator. So, if you want there to be a visible indicator as to the current sorting state of the table, then I recommend that you leave the extra padding there. Otherwise you can do the following:

```
table->setSortingEnabled( true );
table->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicatorShown( false );
```

Note that the order of these function calls matters.

It is also possible to subclass `QHeaderView` and override the virtual `sectionSizeFromContents()` function and customize it to suit your particular needs.

Comment: I thought the same thing about the need for padding for the sort indicator.  However, the indicator is drawn centered above the text, not to the side (at least, for this particular look and feel).  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Updated the answer for another potential solution.